# Jquery Ajax headers change header key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In an old project using jQuery, I pass a header, but the header received bask side has a different name (a different key).

Front, js side:

```js
options.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = CSRFToken;
```

Back, php side

```php
$servers = array();
foreach ($_SERVER as $k=>$v) {
  if (strpos(strtolower($k), 'csrf')) {
    $servers[] = "$k: $v";
  }
}
var_dump($servers);
```

Is actually printing

> HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN: ARandomTokenWeDontCareAbout

Yes, I'm quite sure that this headers is passed at this point, if I remove the js part, HTTP_... disappear.

Is it normal, can I avoid this behaviour, should I deal with it ?

Jquery 2.2, PHP 7.4

Comment: What do you mean "I don't receive as-is"? Is `ARandomTokenWeDontCareAbout` different from `CSFFToken`?

Comment: @Barmar Check header key, not value. I give a header named 'X-CSRF-TOKEN', I receive a header named 'HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN'. Didn't look at the content which should be good

Comment: PHP translates all the `-` to `_` when creating the `$_SERVER` key.